# ClassLoader.getResource("file") works but ClassLoader.getResource("folder/file") does not

Tags: maven, javafx, getresource

In Intellij IDEA, I am trying to load resources in my Maven JavaFX modular project.

Here's my project's structure :

```
myProject
    - src
        - main
            - java
                - com
                    - example
                        - myPackage
                            - myApp.java
                - module-info.java
            - resources
                - fonts
                    - font.ttf
                - font.ttf
```

I duplicated the font I am trying to load in `resources` to test the following :

```java
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL rootFile = loader.getResource("font.ttf"); // this works
URL subfolderFile = loader.getResource("fonts/font.ttf"); // this does not work

System.out.println(rootFile); // file:/C:/Users/... stuff .../myProject/target/classes/font.ttf
System.out.println(subfolderFile); // null, was expecting file:/C:/Users/... stuff .../myProject/target/classes/fonts/font.ttf
```

I was unable to find any posts answering my problem. Does anyone have an explanation ?

Comment: 1. Why `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource()` instead of the usual `someClass.getResource()`? 2. Show the structure of the build folder `target/classes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the documentation of [`ClassLoader#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)):

> Resources in named modules are subject to the encapsulation rules specified by `Module.getResourceAsStream`. Additionally, and except for the special case where the resource has a name ending with ".class", **this method will only find resources in packages of named modules when the package is opened unconditionally** *[emphasis added]* (even if the caller of this method is in the same module as the resource)

You have a `module-info.java` file, so your code is in a named module. The `fonts/font.ttf` resource is in the `fonts` package, so it is [encapsulated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)). Whereas the `font.tff` resource is at the root of the module, meaning it is not in a package, thus it is *not* encapsulated.

If you add:

```java
opens fonts;
```

To your `module-info.java` file then you should be able to load `fonts/font.ttf` via a `ClassLoader`.

That said, it is often simpler to use [`Class#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)). Particularly if the caller, the class, and the resource are all in the same module.